# mysql query help, take total sum from a table, and based on discount value on another table calculate the gross_total

Tags: mysql

I have a table called invoices:

```
`si_invoices` (
  `id` int(10) ,
  `biller_id` int(10) ,
  `customer_id` int(10) ,
  `type_id` int(10) ,
  `inv_tax_id` int(10) ,
  `date` date ,
  `unreg_customer` tinyint(1) ,
  `discount` decimal(10,2) ,
  `discount_type` tinyint(1) 
)
```

each invoice has items that are stored in invoice_items table :

```
 `si_invoice_items` (
  `id` int(10) ,
  `invoice_id` int(10) ,
  `quantity` int(10) ,
  `product_id` int(10) ,
  `warehouse_id` int(10) ,
  `unit_price` decimal(25,2) ,
  `total` decimal(25,2) ,
  `description` text
) ;
```

and tax table

```
`si_tax` (
  `tax_id` int(11),
  `tax_description` varchar(50) ,
  `tax_percentage` decimal(25,6) ,
  `type` varchar(1),
  `tax_enabled` varchar(1) 
) ;
```

here is what I want to do
**step 1:** get the sum_total of the invoice Items for a speciefic invoice
**step 2:** calculate the discount, in the invoice table I have a discount_type field :
         if its equal to 0 , then there will be no discount
         if its equal to 1 , the discount value will be stored in the discount field
         if its equal to 2 , the discount is a percentage of sum_total

**step 3:** calculate the taxes based on inv_tax_id
  based on the tax id , I will look in the tax table , get the tax_percentage and multiply it by the (sum_total - discount)

in short here is the equation
$gross_total = $sum_total - $disount + taxes

Comment: I was inclined to answer your question, but then I noticed that you have never accepted an answer.  I took a quick look, and it seemed that at least one or two could have been marked as answered.  Anyway, I'm sure someone will answer this question for you as well, but please consider reviewing your previous questions when you get a chance.

Comment: how do I accept an answer?, whenever I see a fitting answer I click the up arrow, I'll check to see how to accept an answer

Comment: Ok, now  I get it, click on the image beneath the arrows, I accepted my answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINALLY!!!!!**
I got it to work

here is the query:

```
     SELECT sum( iv.inv_total - iv.inv_discount + iv.taxes ) FROM
 (
SELECT 
        (SELECT sum(ii.total) FROM si_invoice_items ii
            where ii.invoice_id = v.id) as inv_total ,
        (
            SELECT
                CASE v.discount_type
                    WHEN 1 THEN v.discount
                    WHEN 2 THEN (v.discount / 100) * ( SELECT inv_total ) 
                    ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS inv_discount,

        (SELECT 
            CASE t.type
                WHEN '$' THEN t.tax_percentage
                WHEN '%' THEN ( t.tax_percentage / 100 ) * (SELECT inv_total - inv_discount)
                ELSE 0
            END
        FROM si_tax as t
        WHERE t.tax_id = inv_tax_id
        ) AS taxes


    FROM 
        si_invoices v
    ) iv
```

elegant , its a beauty isn't she.. :D

thanks **Arnie** I appreciate your help, and **Mike Pelley** it would've been better if you gave a positive comment or a little help rather than acting as "man of the law"

Comment: I wasn't trying to act as "man of the law" - I was just letting you know why I decided to move on.  It takes a bit of time to answer questions, and there are more questions than time.  Rather than leave silently, I thought I'd let you know in case it helped you get more answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this all in MySQL, but here is the query:

```
SELECT (SELECT `tax_percentage` FROM `si_tax` WHERE `tax_id` = `si_invoices`.`inv_tax_id`) * (`sum_total` - CASE `discount_type` WHEN 1 THEN `discount` WHEN 2 THEN `sum_total` * `discount` / 100 ELSE 0 END) AS `gross`
FROM `si_invoices`
JOIN (SELECT SUM(`total`) AS `sum_total` FROM `si_invoice_items` WHERE `invoice_id` = `si_invoices`.`id`) AS `t`
WHERE `id` = ?
```

Comment: thanks a lot Mr.Arnie
the reason that I want to do it all in mysql is because I'm using phpreports library which takes only a query and executes it and places the result in xml file.

I tried you query , I got an error
so I changed it , then I got the gross = 0x

Comment: SELECT (SELECT `tax_percentage` FROM `si_tax` WHERE `tax_id` = `si_invoices`.`inv_tax_id`) * (`sum_total` - CASE `discount_type` WHEN 1 THEN `discount` WHEN 2 THEN `sum_total` * `discount` / 100 ELSE 0 END) AS `gross`
FROM `si_invoices`
JOIN (SELECT SUM(`total`) AS `sum_total` FROM `si_invoice_items`,`si_invoices` ii WHERE `invoice_id` = ii.id) AS `t`
WHERE `id` = 21
[/code]

Comment: I've come up with this

    SELECT 
  (SELECT sum(ii.total) FROM si_invoice_items ii
   where ii.invoice_id = v.id) as inv_total ,
  (
   SELECT
    CASE v.discount_type
     WHEN 1 THEN v.discount
     WHEN 2 THEN (v.discount / 100) * ( SELECT inv_total ) 
     ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS inv_discount,

  (SELECT 
   CASE t.type
    WHEN '$' THEN t.tax_percentage
    WHEN '%' THEN ( t.tax_percentage / 100 ) * (SELECT inv_total - inv_discount)
    ELSE 0
   END
  FROM si_tax as t
  WHERE t.tax_id = inv_tax_id
  ) AS taxes
  , SELECT sum ( inv_total )

FROM 
 si_invoices v 
but I want to get 1 row!